# Client Side script to check File Size and Type Before Uploading HTML Form thru PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have written an HTML form which uploads data via PHP script.I have put checks in the PHP script, called thru HTML form, to check File Size and Type and this works perfectly fine but,i am looking for a Javascript or a Client Side script which should check File Type and Size before PHP script is executed cause when the  php script is executed and I go back to HTML form all my form data is lost and I have to re-enter whole data again in same form, which i wanna avoid doing.

In simple words, what I want is that I should not be able to post data via PHP script unless file size and file type conditions are satisfied.

Please help, here is my code:

```
        <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>

        <body>

        <form class="form-horizontal" action="submitdesign-add.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <!-- Form Name -->

        <!-- File Button --> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="dname"><mark>UPLOAD YOUR FILE...</mark> <u>Only JPG, JPEG, GIF, PNG files upto size 2 MB are allowed</u></label> 
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="file"  required  maxlength="80" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" >
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>




        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="dname">Name</label>  
          <div class="col-md-8">
          <input id="dname" name="dname" type="text" maxlength="45" placeholder="Enter Your Name here" class="form-control input-md" required="">

          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="demail">Email</label>  
          <div class="col-md-8">
          <input id="demail" name="demail" type="email" maxlength="45" placeholder="Enter Your Email here" class="form-control input-md">

          </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <br>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+upload+file+check+size

Comment: perfect answer @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file size and type by jquery, use this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $('#fileToUpload').bind('change', function() {
            //For size checks
            var file_size = this.files[0].size;
            if(file_size>2097152) {
                alert("File size is greater than 2MB");
                return false;
            }

            //For extension checks
            var filename = $("#fileToUpload").val();
            var extension = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');
            if (extension == 'jpg' || extension == 'jpeg' || extension == 'png' || extension == 'gif') {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert("Invalid file type");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Manav, I tried adding this script in my HTML form but its not working. Its still going to my PHP script and checking it there. To be Frank and Honest.. I am not able to configure your script properly in  my form as I am not that good at Javascript. Can I request you to please help me further if possible.. Thnx in advance

Comment: Vikram, I want your whole code then i make a Fiddle for you which help you more.

Comment: Thank You Manav. I have managed to get my work done. SO much Thnx for ur help friend